# Conditional Format with reference cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to a range of cells based on information contained in reference cells.

Column A is a name field populated by a form submission, column B is a number field populated by a form submission.

Column D is the reference name and column E is the reference number, both are populated manually.

I want to format column A and B if the name in column A is equal to the reference name AND below the reference number.

I know this is nowhere near the correct formula but logically speaking this is what I'm looking to do. "if A2:A = D2, and B2:B < E2" cells A and B will be formatted.

My account is new so I'm not able to embed images so the link is below:

Example Screenshot:

[image: Example Screen Shot[1]]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SWLiJHC3YD-Tr6wy7tPL2xtvrXEHr-PLMBLzJ2HJ5u0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

This should fulfill your criteria (it's a array formula, ctrl + shift + enter):

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(ArrayFormula(MATCH(1,($A2=$D$2:$D$4)*($B2<$E$2:$E$4),0)),FALSE))
```

For the values where the match formula is not matched it will produce a #N/A result. Therefore we wrap the match formula with an IFERROR formula.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. THANK YOU!